# Hashtable copy leads to null pointer

Tags: java, collections, nullpointerexception, hashtable

I'm having a problem trying to copy a hashtable then adding some values. I have two different hashtables(for debug purposes). The first hashtable I declare and set it equal to another hashtable.

```
Hashtable model1 = model;
```

The second hashtable is declared and initialized with the original hashtable which should copy every single element and key into the new Hashtable.

```
Hashtable model2 = new Hashtable(model);
```

However, when I try to get a element back from model2, it always throws a NullPointerException. However, the first instance(model1) doesn't throw anything(though it doesn't give me the results I want because it adds a reference to the model instance). Any help or advice would e appreciated!! :)

Comment: Please post the code that throws the NPE.

Comment: _"when I try to get a element back from model2, it always throws a NullPointerException"_.  Please show the code you use to retrieve values.

Comment: _boolean result = (Boolean)model.get(this.uniqueSymbol);_ This is the statement that gives me the exception and it also happens in another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean result = (Boolean)model.get(this.uniqueSymbol);
```

If the value you are retrieving is null, you are getting a null `Boolean` object but then the JVM is trying to auto-unbox it to a primitive, but since the value is null, you get a null pointer exception.  You should verify that the value you are trying to get is in fact not null.  Try it without the auto-unboxing behavior and see what happens.

```
Boolean result = (Boolean)model.get(this.uniqueSymbol);
```

From the [JavaDoc for Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29): Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, **or null** if this map contains no mapping for the key.

Comment: Is there anyway for me to recast Boolean to its primitive form. I tried the Boolean.booleanValue() but it throws the same exception.

Comment: Well if you are really getting a null there's no way to turn it in to a primitive directly since null isn't necessarily true or false in Java.  I'm guessing you could do something like this:

    Boolean b = (Boolean)model.get(this.uniqueSymbol);
    boolean result = b == null ? false : b.booleanValue();